# How to pass a list/array of structs from python to C

Tags: python, c, list, pointers, struct

I have a C function that must be callable from C and Python.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass a python list of c-type structs,
each of which contains several nested structs, to the c function.

A single one of these structs looks like this in python:

```
class STATION_MM_NODE(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ("signal", MM_STRUCT),
            ("noise", MM_STRUCT),
            ("signalWindowLen", ctypes.c_double),
            ("metadata", SAC_PZ)
    ]
```

And like this in C:

```
typedef struct stationMMnode {
    struct mantleMagStruct *signal;
    struct mantleMagStruct *noise;
    double signalWindowLen;
    SAC_PZ metadata;
} stationMMnode_t;
```

The c function that takes an array of stationMMnode structs is callable as:

```
double magnitudeCompute_Mw_Mm_Event(stationMMnode_t **stationMMarray, int numStations);
```

For instance, I can call it purely from C as in:

```
int testfunc() {
    stationMMnode_t *node1 = malloc(sizeof(struct stationMMnode));
    node1->signalWindowLen = 500;
    stationMMnode_t *node2 = malloc(sizeof(struct stationMMnode));
    node2->signalWindowLen = 100;

    struct stationMMnode *nodes[2];
    nodes[0] = node1;
    nodes[1] = node2;

    magnitudeCompute_Mw_Mm_Event(nodes, 2); // Works!
}
```

In python, I can create a list of nodes that looks similar to the c array of structs:

```
stationMMnodes = []
...
node = get_stationMMnode() # Returns a STATION_MM_NODE
node.signal = mm_signal
node.noise  = mm_noise
node.metadata = sacPoleZero
stationMMnodes.append(node)
...
wrap_lib.magnitudeCompute_Mw_Mm_Event(stationMMnodes, numStations) # Does NOT work
```

where I've defined the argtypes as:

```
wrap_lib.magnitudeCompute_Mw_Mm_Event.argtypes =
    [ctypes.POINTER(STATION_MM_NODE), ctypes.c_int ]
```

The model I'm using above (passing a ctype pointer to a c-style struct to a c function that takes a pointer to struct) seems to work fine when I am passing in a pointer to a single struct, however, for a pointer to an array of structs, it seems to break down.  In addition, I am uncertain of what the python memory layout is for a list of structs versus an array of pointers to struct (as the C function is expecting).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I found the following link very helpful:
[python ctypes array of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101845/python-ctypes-array-of-structs)

I solved my problem by:
1. Declaring an array of pointers to my struct:

```
nodeArrayType = ctypes.POINTER(STATION_MM_NODE) * 1024
nodeArray = nodeArrayType()
nstn = 0
```

2. Writing a C function to join the member structs into a larger struct (=a node) and return a pointer to that struct - which is stored in nodeArray[].

```
nodeArray[nstn] = wrap_libmth.libmth.makeNode(node.signal, node.noise, node.metadata)
nstn += 1
```

3. Fixing the argtype of the C function that receives the pointer to struct array:

```
wrap_libmth.libmth.magnitudeCompute_Mw_Mm_Event.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(STATION_MM_NODE)), ctypes.c_int]
```

So ... I have it working, but like most thing with Python, I feel like I'm holding the tiger by the tail as I don't fully understand exactly why it works and what (better) alternatives would be (e.g., the C hack makeNode() to return a pointer to a STATION_MM_NODE struct is less than satisfactory - it would be better to generate this struct fully in python).

Comment: I have done something similar. In my case though, the nested structs were declared as an actual array in the parent struct together with a length variable. In that case, the python glue code is trivial (just declare an array by multiplying the type with a scalar).

Comment: Update: I found the following post helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101845/python-ctypes-array-of-structs