# How can a type be incompatible with itself?

Tags: python, django, ctypes

In my django application (Django 1.6.0, python 2.7.5 running on Red Hat), my database driver is seeing an error from ctypes:

> TypeError: incompatible types, LP_c_int instance instead of LP_c_int instance

The code looks like this:

```
    is_null = value is None
    param.value.is_null = pointer(c_int(is_null)) <-- error occurs on this line
```

I'm not really familiar with ctypes (I inherited this code) but on the surface, this error message makes no sense. The code has been running for years but I'm now seeing this error all over the place. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Here is a minimal repro thanks to the comment from Ilja Everilä:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import _reset_cache

class DataValue(Structure):
    """Must match a_sqlany_data_value."""

    _fields_ = [("buffer",      POINTER(c_char)),
                ("buffer_size", c_size_t),
                ("length",      POINTER(c_size_t)),
                ("type",        c_int),
                ("is_null",     POINTER(c_int))]

d = DataValue()
_reset_cache()
is_null = False
d.is_null = pointer( c_int( is_null ) )
```

Comment: "LP_c_int instance instead of LP_c_int instance" awards you a +1

Comment: Did you upgrade the python used in the environment?

Comment: @Jieter Not recently.

Comment: could you create a [mcve] so we can torture your code and try to make it confess?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/sqlanywhere/sqlanydb/blob/master/sqlanydb.py#L402) the offending line btw?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the error if I manually first construct a `DataValue` instance, then call `ctypes._pointer_type_cache.clear()` or `ctypes._reset_cache()`, and then try the assignment.

Comment: For better or worse, ctypes relies extensively on Python runtime type checking. A pointer type is a subclass of `ctypes._Pointer` with a given `_type_`.  ctypes uses `ctypes._pointer_type_cache` to ensure consistency, so we don't end up with multiple Python types that reference the same `_type_`. That's why pointer types are normally created via `POINTER` and `pointer` instead of directly subclassing `_Pointer`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17102186/2961550) to a similar question helped me solve this issue by `cast`ing the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, and in my case it had to do with pre-defining empty `Structure`s to get around having circular references. I was doing something like this:

```py
from ctypes import Structure, POINTER, pointer, c_int

class B(Structure):
    pass

class A(Structure):
    _fields_ = (('b_ref', POINTER(B)),)

class B(Structure):
    _fields_ = (('a_ref', POINTER(A)),)

b = B()
a = A()

a.b_ref = pointer(b)
b.a_ref = pointer(a)
```

which gives the result:

> TypeError: incompatible types, LP_B instance instead of LP_B instance

What an un-helpful message...

The comments clued me in to the existence of the ctypes cache, which made me realize the re-definition was the problem. The solution was to simply pre-define all the classes before setting `_fields_`:

```py
from ctypes import Structure, POINTER, pointer, c_int

class A(Structure): pass
class B(Structure): pass


A._fields_ = (('b_ref', POINTER(B)),)
B._fields_ = (('a_ref', POINTER(A)),)

b = B()
a = A()

a.b_ref = pointer(b)
b.a_ref = pointer(a)
```

Regarding your exact issue with the native `c_int` however, I believe it may be related to Django's dev server capability to re-load any changed modules. I have never used django however and it would be difficult for me to test (especially considering the age of the post). `ctypes` automatically calls `_reset_cache()` on import. Normally repeated calls to `import ...` simply get a cached version of the library, so I would assume it must be related to some sort of `importlib.reload(...)` like call.